# Why View Result Tree listener not showing individual requests under transaction controller

Tags: jmeter-5.0

I'm preparing a JMeter plan as simple as the steps below

1. Open Home Page
2. Click on "Shop" link
3. Click "Region"

this plan can be seen in picture "Project plan-A"

[image]

But when this plan is executed the `View Result Tree` does not show me individual requests under respective "Transaction Controllers" which are "Open Home Page, Open Shop Page, Open Region" etc I thought the tree would show me some thing like

1--> Open Home Page
1a. 138/home
2--> Open Shop Page
2a. 173 /Middle-East/UAE.....
2b. 187 /product/.....
but instead it is showing me some like
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your project tree choose the [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) and check `Generate parent sample`

[image]

After that you can see each nested request under transaction controller in your `View Results Tree`
[image]

> In parent mode, the individual samples can still be seen in the Tree View Listener, but no longer appear as separate entries in other Listeners. Also, the sub-samples do not appear in CSV log files, but they can be saved to XML files.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me after anabling the "generate parent sample"